# Short story where the labour class lives in another timeline to the privileged class

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, soft-sci-fi

A short story was mentioned to me and we are trying to figure out the name of it.
It was apparently written years ago and was hoping to find it.

It was apparently a short story based around divided classes. One class lived the good life where the other was used as labour making stuff needed by the privileged class.

Because the labour class were in a different timeline, the privileged class could ask for stuff, and get it quick, no matter how long it takes to make, because they run on different timelines.

Every generation, the classes would switch, so if you were in the privileged class, your children would have to go to the labour class/timeline (and vice versa), and their children can go to the privileged timeline.

A key part of the story revolves around a father who doesn't want his child to go to the labour class, so tries to hide him.

Comment: _"It was apparently written years ago"_ - do you happen to know how many years ago this would be? If so could you [edit] that into the question?

Comment: I read a book length story with this in ( < 1990?), a man attempting to circumvent the generational swap by concealing his son, so they are punished by being sent to the labouring class zone. In the story the Earth is under the control of a Fascist  group called "The Titans" who have confined other racial groups to reservations. The hero is an archaeologist who enlists the help of the divided-class society (which is housed in a giant hour-glass shaped space-ship) against the Titans. End is hero attempting to get the labourers to revolt "you have nothing to lose but your chains"

Answer (score 6):

I think this is probably the novel [Collision Course](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_Course_(Bayley_novel)) by Barrington J. Bayley, that was identified by Handsome Jim in a comment.

This is a novel not a short story, but scenario that you describe appears as part of the novel. It's a description of the society on a space station called Retort City. The city has mastered the manipulation of time. For example they have a table tennis games where different areas of the table are in slightly different timezones and they play a variant of chess where the two players are in different timezones.

The city is divided exactly as you describe:

> Colloquially the two halves of the ISS were known as the Lower Retort and the Upper Retort – terms with social, rather than spatial implications. Officially they were the Production Retort and Leisure Retort. And no one, except newborn babes, ever passed from one retort to the other.
>
> Or almost no one.

Su-Mueng is the child that the father tried to keep in the Upper Resort/Leisure zone:

> His father was Hueh Shao, once an official of high rank – a cabinet minister, Su-Mueng believed – in the Leisure Retort. There must have been something badly maladjusted about Hueh Shao, for in a society where for centuries everyone had been faultlessly conditioned into accepting the long-established custom, he had been unable to bear the thought of sending his newborn son down into the Lower Retort. He had broken the law, secretly keeping the babe and representing it as his grandson sent up from below.
>
> It seemed incredible that the deception could go undetected, let alone that Su-Mueng’s absence from his proper place could go unnoticed, but somehow Hueh had managed it for ten full years. Then his crime had come to light. And the law was the law: there could be no exceptions. Su-Mueng, having been raised in what was probably the most refined culture the galaxy had to offer, and despite his tender years, had been sent down to live with total strangers in a different, cruder environment.

Comment: I'm curious as to how much faster time moved for the Lower Retort.  It would seem that the population there would age and die out faster than it would be replaced by children from the Upper Retort.